# Are both XML attributes for newer and older APIs needed?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, xml-attribute

Should I specify both XML attributes for newer and older APIs in my AndroidManifest file if the minSdk is set to API 11? If not, which one should I specify?

**Here is an example of using both `parentActivityName` attributes:**

```
<activity
      android:name=".SettingsActivity"
      android:label="@string/action_settings"
      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
      <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value=".MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: Chakeretim Khobi As Iran dari post mikoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation:

> The android:parentActivityName attribute declares the name of this
>   activity's parent activity within the app's logical hierarchy. The
>   system uses this value to implement default navigation behaviors, such
>   as Up navigation on Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher. You can
>   provide the same navigation behaviors for older versions of Android by
>   using the Support Library and adding the  element as shown
>   here.

So it means yes! You need to indicate both attributes if your minimum API requires.

Cheers
A.